# XML php variable element number

Tags: php, xml

```
 $aid= $_GET["aid"];
 echo $xml->orders->ITEM["$aid"]->name;
```

With this script I'm trying to display the value of an XML page.
The variable `$aid` is the number of elements. 
This can be 0 to 1000.

Only nothing displays when I run this script.

This works fine

```
 $aid= $_GET["aid"];
 echo $xml->orders->ITEM[1]->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the key wrong, use just the variable name without the apostrophes.

```
echo $xml->orders->ITEM[$aid]->name;
```

Comment: "$aid" is same as $aid except "$aid" is bad in terms of performance.I think that's what Kasia tried to say.

Answer (score 1):

Use an integer key, values from `$_GET` are strings.

```
$aid = (int) $_GET["aid"];
echo $xml->orders->ITEM[$aid]->name;
```

With SimpleXML, integer values denote an element in a collection (e.g. `0` is the first, `1` is the second) whereas string values denote attributes of that name.

I'm assuming the value isn't just a number (since SimpleXML can recognise that, even as a string).